# Have column with multiple values and want to put values into one cell based on unique value

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am dealing with three tables - "Assignment Table", "Instructor Table," & "Course Table".

Assignment Table contains this type of information:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ro7oV.png)

Course Table contains this type of information:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsTtV.png)

Instructor Table contains this type of information:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0k0IJ.png)

The goal is to take the multiple values from the assignment table and place them in the single value tables in one cell based on the current year.

I have thought about utilizing the to try and solve for current course assignments within instructor table but receive error

Current Assignments =
VAR _IND = instructors[Instructor] RETURN
CONCATENATEX(
CALCULATETABLE(
VALUES(Assignment[Course]),
cre49_instructors[Instructor] >= _IND && cre49_instructors[Instructor] < _IND + CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Assignment),FILTER(Assignment,assignment[Instructor])),
REMOVEFILTERS(Assignment)
),
Assignment[course]," ,",Assignment[course]
)

But I am not sure this is correct and in any event, I keep getting an error.

Can this be achieved in PowerBI? I want to do this because it cleaner view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these measures:

```
Current Instructor = 
CALCULATE(
    CONCATENATEX(
        'Table',
        'Table'[Instructor],
        "; "
    ),
    'Table'[Year] = DATEVALUE("2023-01-01")
)
```

and

```
Current Course = 
CALCULATE(
    CONCATENATEX(
        'Table',
        'Table'[Course],
        "; "
    ),
    'Table'[Year] = DATEVALUE("2023-01-01")
)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! This worked out great for me! Thank you for informing me of the direction I could take it, Peter!